# C++ Дано массив из 20 элементов. Найти пять соседних элементов, сумма значений которых максимальная

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Дано массив из 20 элементов. Найти пять соседних элементов, сумма значений которых максимальная

Comment: берете по 5 элементов с начала и считаете сумму. потом сдвиг на единицу и по новой и так пока не найдете максимум.

Comment: Вся идея, ради которой формулируют такие обучающие задачи: научить студента идее инкрементального вычисления текущей суммы. Для перехода от предыдущей суммы к следующей нужно вычесть уходящий элемент и добавить приходящий. Я смотрю, никто из решателей пока не потрудился реализовать такой проход по массиву.

Comment: @AnT просим Вас опубликовать Ваше решение. Критикуешь - предлагай ))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Постарался сделать на современном *C++* (не мой основной язык):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <stdexcept>
using std::invalid_argument;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

constexpr size_t range_size = 5;

int sum(const vector<int> &v) {
  int s = 0;
  for (auto const e : v) {
    s += e;
  }

  return s;
}

vector<int> greatest_subvector_of_5(const vector<int> &v) {
  if (v.size() < range_size) {
    throw invalid_argument("too few elements");
  }

  auto max_sv = vector(v.begin(), v.begin() + range_size);
  auto max_sum = sum(max_sv);

  for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size() - range_size + 1; i++) {
    auto sv = vector(v.begin() + i, v.begin() + i + range_size);
    auto s = sum(sv);

    if (s > max_sum) {
      max_sv = sv;
      max_sum = s;
    }
  };

  return max_sv;
}

int main() {
  auto const v = vector{
      0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0,
  };

  vector<int> sv;
  try {
    sv = greatest_subvector_of_5(v);
  } catch (const invalid_argument &e) {
    return 1;
  }

  cout << "greatest subvector: ";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sv.size(); i++) {
    auto e = sv.at(i);
    cout << e;

    if (i != sv.size() - 1) {
      cout << ", ";
    }
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что то тут нету современного с++

Comment: для простой задачи, где нужен  всего один цикл, написали две функции плюс обработка исключения, которое никогда не возникнет, если вы просто не выйдете за пределы вектора.   if (v.size() < range_size) просто нужно  выдать результат суммы элементов...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan согласен, автор ответа усложнил простое...

Comment: @Andrey, по моему вы тоже усложнили немного

Comment: @ARHovsepyan , уже исправил ) может Вы свой вариант представите и уважите нас? Хочется посмотреть на решение человека с Вашим рейтингом

Comment: @Andrey, вариантов можно предложить сотни, но эта простая задача, которую вы стараетесь выполнить за ТС не стоит так много обсуждений(мне даже неловко стало).  Всегда лучше решать просто, а не показывать свои  все знания  языка и стандартной библиотеки,  Вы же сами написали правильный ответ в своем первом комментарии к вопросу

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я ни разу не сомневаюсь, что Вы решите эту задачу ) и да я согласен, тривиальная задача, 4 ответа и тьма обсуждений ) я думаю мы с Вами схлестнёмся в каком нибудь другом вопросе, требующим подробного обсуждения )

Comment: @Andrey, Я тут  помогаю  другим и себя, может заодно и развлекаюсь, решая некоторые проблемы,  а не играю в игры и ни с кем не соревнуюсь. Я давно уже  не школьник... Да, забыл отметить, что считаю сайт очень полезным и стараюсь всячески поддерживать его активность

Answer (score 2):

> Вообще в голову не лезет как это написать.

*Помогаю реализовать:*

Вы можете найти сумму пяти элементов массива, которые идут подряд, начиная с самого первого элемента массива? А начиная с самого второго? А с третьего? И так далее. Запоминайте в переменные индекс начала пятерки с самой большой суммой и саму сумму. Не забудьте остановиться за пять элементов до конца массива, чтобы не залезть за его границу.

Answer (score 2):

И сказал Окаам: не преумножайте сущности сверх необходимости. И добавил: пишите код попроще, но никто не понимал, что значит "код" и вторую часть забыли.

```
std::vector<int> vec{1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 12, 23, 55, 12, 1,
                     31, 32, 55, 23, 11, 4, 4, 1, 0, 2};
int idx = 4;
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) sum += vec[i];
int max = sum;
for(int i = 5; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    sum += vec[i] - vec[i-5];
    if (max < sum) { max = sum; idx = i; }
    }
cout << vec[idx-4] << "+" << vec[idx-3] << "+" << vec[idx-2] << "+"
    << vec[idx-1] << "+" << vec[idx] << "=" << max << endl;
```

Comment: Я бы принял именно этот ответ...

Answer (score -1):

Все просто, найдите все суммы группами по 5 элементов.
Дальше возьмите максимум и запомните его итератор )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>


int main() {

    std::vector<int> vec{1, 3111, 2111, 4111, 5111, 1211, 23, 55, 12, 1, 31, 32, 55, 23, 11, 4, 4, 1, 0, 2};
    auto it{std::begin(vec)};
    auto res_it{std::begin(vec)};

    long int size{5};

    long int max{std::numeric_limits<size_t>::min()};

    do {
        auto sum = std::accumulate(it, it + size, 0);
        if (sum > max) {
            max = sum;
            res_it = it;
        }
        it = std::next(it);
    } while (it != (std::end(vec) - size));

    std::cout << "max sum : " << max << " position of 1st elem : " << res_it - std::begin(vec) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В чем, интересно, глубинный смысл выноса пятерки в отдельный вектор? Уже второй автор это упорно делает. Вот ума не приложу, как может в голову такое прийти. Я могу еще понять постоянные перевычисления суммы (для студента сойдет), но  вынос в отдельный вектор... ума не приложу. Также не ясно, почему использована такая мешанина способов инициализации - то `{}`,  то `=`, то `()`.

Comment: @AnT немного намешанная нотация, да. Можно избавится от временного вектора. Согласен. Пятница ночь ))) . Перевычисоение тоже можно заменить на вычитание указателя на начало группы из 5 элементов и прибавление нового конца, да надо переписать )